# Class method returning empty array

Tags: objective-c

I have written a class method that converts columnar data from a text file and returns an array of arrays...only it is returning an EMPTY array of EMPTY arrays.

```
+(NSArray *) initArrayWithFileContents:(NSString *) theFilePath
{
NSString *theContents = [self loadFile:theFilePath];
NSArray *theParagraphs = [self getParagraphs:theContents];

NSMutableArray *teamData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];       // array of team data
NSMutableArray *leagueData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];     // array of arrays

// set up number formatters for getting numbers from strings
NSNumberFormatter *numberStyle = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSNumberFormatter *positiveNumberStyle = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberStyle setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[positiveNumberStyle setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[positiveNumberStyle setPositiveFormat:@"'+'#"];

// set up a date and time formatter for getting time data from strings
NSDateFormatter *timeStyle = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeStyle setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[timeStyle setDateFormat:@" mm:ss"];

for (NSString *currentParagraph in theParagraphs)
{
    NSArray *currentTeam = [self getcolumnarData:currentParagraph]; // get an array of strings
    for (NSString *currentItem in currentTeam)
    {
        NSNumber *currentStat = [numberStyle numberFromString:currentItem];
        if (currentStat != Nil) {
            [teamData addObject:currentStat];           // number found

        } else {
            currentStat = [positiveNumberStyle numberFromString:currentItem];
            if (currentStat != Nil) {
                [teamData addObject:currentStat];       // number with '+' sign found

            } else {
                NSDate *currentTime = [timeStyle dateFromString:currentItem];
                if (currentTime != Nil) {
                    NSNumber *theSeconds = [self calculateSeconds: currentTime];
                    [teamData addObject:theSeconds];    // time found

                } else {
                    [teamData addObject:currentItem];   // string found
                }
            }
        }
    }
    [leagueData addObject:teamData];    // add child array to end of parent array
    [teamData removeAllObjects];        // reset child array
}
NSArray *dataToReturn = [NSArray arrayWithArray:leagueData]; // convert to NSArray to return
return dataToReturn;
}
```

In my debugging efforts I have verified that either an NSString or NSNumber is being added to the end of the `teamData` array but when adding `teamData` to `leagueData` an empty object is added. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance,
Brad

Comment: An empty array of empty arrays does not make sense, the first array is not empty since it contains a bunch of empty arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move

```
NSMutableArray *teamData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

into the loop:

```
for (NSString *currentParagraph in theParagraphs)
{
    NSMutableArray *teamData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // ...

    [leagueData addObject:teamData];
}
```

loop. At present, you always add *the same array* to `leagueData`.
An array "only" keeps pointers to its elements, so at the end all elements
of `leagueData` point to the same array `teamData` (from which you have removed
all objects).

Comment: Martin,  Thank you for your suggestion. I realized what I was doing AFTER I posted the question. I'm not used to working with pointers yet. I moved the `teamData` line as you suggested and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks...I tried to vote your answer up but I don't yet have enough points for that. I have "accepted" your answer now.